# Non- unity exponential increments of argument in a power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

A power series is exponentiated in unity increments $n$ for each new term before summing up:

$$
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty ,1}  \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$

However if in a power series instead, a non-unity increment in power of $x$ terms with say a real number is incorporated like :
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty ,\frac{\pi}{2}}  \dfrac{x^n}{n!}=  1 + \frac{x^{\pi/2}}{{(\pi/2)}!}+\frac{x^{2\pi/2}}{{(2\pi/2)}!} + 
\frac{x^{3\pi/2}}{{(3\pi/2)}!} +\frac{x^{4\pi/2}}{{(4\pi/2)}!} +..+\frac{x^{n\pi/2}}{{(n\pi/2)}!}+..; $$

$$ (n \frac{\pi}{2})!= \Gamma{(n \frac{\pi}{2}+1});$$

EDIT1:

and for $p$ real if generalized to:

$$ f_p(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty ,p } \dfrac{x^n}{n!}=  1 + \frac{x^p}{{p}!}+ \frac{x^{2p}}{{(2p)}!} + 
\frac{x^{3p}}{{(3p)}!} +\frac{x^{4p}}{{(4p)}!} +..+\frac{x^{np}}{{(np)}!}+..; $$

$$ (n p)!= \Gamma{(n p+1});$$

Can such an $f_p(x)$ exist?

If so, does it converge?

If it does, to what function? Can the functions

$$f_{\frac12}(x), f_{-\frac12}(x), $$

be graphed on $x?$

Does the question make sense at all ? ( Topic is not exactly my forte .. )

Comment: Define $\sum_0^{\infty,\frac\pi2}f_n(x)$.

Comment: Somewhat like as given above.

Comment: The existence of $f(x)$ has to do with the convergence of the series. For the values of $x$ that this series converges $f(x)$ "exists".

Comment: The example series is given by $1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(x^{\pi/2})^n}{(n\pi/2)\Gamma(n\pi/2)}$, which converges for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.